# How to make node execute synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronous

I'm using node to read a file, then compile a pdf based on some info that is in that file. I've got the entire thing to do what I want, so I don't think details are that important. It does exactly what I need it to do when I manually enter it line by line, but when I try to have node execute the entire thing as a javascript file, it throws errors saying I've got undefined variables. Here's my script:

```
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
    var hummus = require('hummus')
    var fs = require('fs');
    var parse = require('csv-parse');


    var tabDelimitedText = fs.readFileSync('/volumes/merge central/fip automation/working/tab-delimited.txt',{encoding:"UTF-8"})
    var parsedText;
    parse(tabDelimitedText , {delimiter:"\t"}, function(err, output){parsedText = output});


    //get client info from parsed text
    var orderNumber = parsedText[1][0];
    var clientName = parsedText[1][1];
    var coverText = "FIP_" + orderNumber + " " + clientName;
    var finishedPDFName = '/volumes/merge central/fip automation/~~~orders/FIP_' + orderNumber + "." + clientName + ".pdf"
    var qtyColumn = 2;
    var fileNameColumn = 3;


    //this section is making the coverpage with pdfkit
    var pageOptions = {size:[432,450]};
    doc = new PDFDocument(pageOptions);
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(finishedPDFName));
    doc.font('Helvetica-Bold').fontSize(25).text(coverText,0,200,{align:"center",width:432});
    doc.end();


    //opens the working pdf to be modified by hummus
    var pdfWriter = hummus.createWriterToModify(finishedPDFName)

    //this section appends files onto coverpage based on the tab delimited file
    for (thisRow = 1; thisRow < parsedText.length; thisRow++) {
        //gets data from parsed text file
        var thisQty = parsedText[thisRow][qtyColumn];
        var thisTrueQty = thisQty/6
        var thisFileName = "FIP_" + parsedText[thisRow][fileNameColumn];
        var thisPDFtoInsert = "/Volumes/MERGE CENTRAL/FIP AUTOMATION/Found Image Press Calendars/" + thisFileName;

        for (i = 0; i < thisTrueQty; i++) {
            pdfWriter.appendPDFPagesFromPDF(thisPDFtoInsert);
        }
    }

    //closes pdf
    pdfWriter.end();
```

I'm pretty new to node so excuse any of my ignorance, but, as far as I can tell, node tries very hard to be asynchronous and I think that's my problem. I'm guessing that the script goes on to declare variables before that file has been read and parsed entirely. The error I get says "Cannot read property '1' of undefined" referencing the line `var orderNumber = parsedText[1][0];`. So my thought is that `parsedText` is in the process of being defined when the script tries to execute `var orderNumber = parsedText[1][0];`

Am I correct in my understanding of what's happening? Is there any workaround that can force the script to wait until certain functions finish before continuing on? I'm sure it's not too complicated, I'm just in a little over my head here I think, and I'm not having any luck figuring it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Welcome to Stack Overflow!**

First, there's no need to excuse yourself for being a newbie, we've all been there and you seem to have done your research before posting your question. Kudos for trying to learn new things!

You are right about Node being asynchronous, in this case it means a few things :

You should put EVERYTHING inside the :

```
parse(tabDelimitedText , {delimiter:"\t"}, function(err, output){

parsedText = output
//all the rest here
});
```

then you'll find that the pdfWriter.end will be executed before your for loop has finished its job. In this case, you can solve this by calling the .end() from within your loop, after the last iteration :

```
//this section appends files onto coverpage based on the tab delimited file
for (thisRow = 1; thisRow < parsedText.length; thisRow++) {
    //gets data from parsed text file
    var thisQty = parsedText[thisRow][qtyColumn];
    //if (thisQty != "") {
        var thisTrueQty = thisQty/6
        var thisFileName = "FIP_" + parsedText[thisRow][fileNameColumn];
        var thisPDFtoInsert = "/Volumes/MERGE CENTRAL/FIP AUTOMATION/Found Image Press Calendars/" + thisFileName;

        //inserts the pdf thisQty times
        for (i = 0; i < thisTrueQty; i++) {
            pdfWriter.appendPDFPagesFromPDF(thisPDFtoInsert);
            if(i==thisTrueQty-1){
                //closes pdf
                pdfWriter.end();
            }
        }
    //}
}
```

One way to avoid to have callbacks inside callbacks inside callbacks is to use libraries like Q or async which will enable you to make synchronous behaviour. But I guess you first have to realize what a [Pyramid Of Doom](http://tritarget.org/blog/2012/11/28/the-pyramid-of-doom-a-javascript-style-trap/) is!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I appreciate it. The method you suggested seems to have worked just like I wanted. Thanks for the help!